# PyQt - Toggle Frame Resize Push Button

Tags: python, pyqt

I am having a problem with resizing the frame based on the clicking of a single button. I have a blank window with a single push button called `pushButton` in my ui file. I would like that whenever this button is pressed, the dimensions of the MainWindow are changed, however the resizing only happens one time. The original dimensions are 640 by 480.

What I am doing incorrectly in the `run_resize` function? Thanks!

The code is as follows.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

qtCreatorFile = 'my_gui.ui'
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())

        self.frame = QFrame()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run_resize)

    def run_resize(self):
        if self.frame.height() == 480:
            self.setMinimumSize(640, 150)
            self.resize(640, 150)
        else:
            self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
            self.resize(640, 480)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = main_window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your condition is on the `frame` object and you set the size of your `QMainWindow`. Try to replace `if self.frame.height() == 480:` by `if self.height() == 480:`

Comment: Wow, thanks! this was it!

Comment: No problem :) I wrote an answer so it may help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the condition on the `QMainWindow`, here is a working example :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

qtCreatorFile = 'my_gui.ui'
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run_resize)

    def run_resize(self):
        if self.height() == 480:
            self.setMinimumSize(640, 150)
            self.resize(640, 150)
        else:
            self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
            self.resize(640, 480)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```